# Trouble combining 3 different SQL tables items and getting the sum

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am having trouble with a system that my dad uses for reporting at his company. I didn't build it but I am trying my best to wrap my head around it. It's ASP and I am not so well versed in it (or writing sql for that matter).

Basically I have three tables I am working with, Item, ItemHistory, and Devices. In those tables what I am trying to do is

- Get the items a user has worked on via the "serialnumber" column from the "Item History" table
- Compare that serial number to the "serialnumber" column in the "Item" table to get the device type (from the device column)
- Use the device type to grab a predetermined number value from "points" column in the "Devices" table
- Store the value and add it to any other values that were pulled back by the query then display the total.

**See Update**

As you can see, it would have been much easier if the Device Type was included in the ItemHistory table, but it wasn't. I've tried JOINing the tables but keep getting errors (which is from my lack of knowledge im fairly certain). The query is by date range and user (from the ItemHistory table), but I think I've got that figured out. I just can't get it to reference all the tables and add the "points" together.

Any help is greatly appreciated! If you need any more info let me know. Thank you in advance.

---

Update

So basically what I am having problems with now is that the query keeps coming back with "Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record." which I think is being caused because it is just adding the numbers in the points column.

I think the problem with my last question is that I made it seem like there were "Points" for every device, but really there are a set number of devices (lets say five) and there could be multiple serial numbers all pointing at one device. I think this is where the query is running into trouble (but I could be wrong). Also, my sql statement looks pretty much exactly like the one littlebobbytables posted below, except for my own variables added in.

Here's what the database looks like.

ItemHistory Table

> ```
> Date      | SerialNumber |  DeviceType | User
> ----------|--------------|-------------|-------
> 11/1/12   | 123-456-789  |     NULL    | Bill
> 11/1/12   | 456-123-987  |     NULL    | Bill
> 11/1/12   | 987-654-321  |     NULL    | Bill
> 11/1/12   | 216-897-631  |     NULL    | Bill
> 11/1/12   | 874-547-277  |     NULL    | Bill
> ```

Item Table

> ```
>   SerialNumber |  DeviceType
>   -------------|-------------
>   123-456-789  |  Device1
>   456-123-987  |  Device2
>   987-654-321  |  Device3
>   216-897-631  |  Device1
>   874-547-277  |  Device2
> ```

Devices Table

> ```
>   Device   |  Points
>  ----------|----------
>   Device1  |    20
>   Device2  |    25
>   Device3  |    40
> ```

And what I am hoping the output will be is

> ```
>   User   |  Points
>  --------|----------
>   Bill   |    130
> ```

Comment: +1: The question itself is neither new nor innovative on this site. BUT you have made quite some effort _right from the start_ to bring clear examples and nice formatting too. Keep up the good style.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the points together, and group by the User ID:

```
SELECT [User], SUM(Points) AS Points
FROM ItemHistory IH
INNER JOIN Item I ON IH.SerialNumber = I.SerialNumber
INNER JOIN Devices D ON I.DeviceType = D.Device
WHERE IH.[Date] = @YourDateVariable
GROUP BY [User]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your help! Now I am running into an error "]Non unique column reference: User. I can only assume it is because there is a User column in the "Items" Table (the person who initially put it in the system) and one in the ItemHistory table. I didn't include it in my original question because I didn't think it would matter much. Is there anything I can do to fix this? aside from changing the column names, i mean.

Comment: Certainly, you can use the table name (or in this case the alias) to refer to a specific `[User]` field.  You can do `SELECT I.[User]` and `GROUP BY I.[User]`.

Comment: I know it's been a while but hopefully you can help me again, I had to put this on hold and am just now revisiting it and I think I'm getting closer. The problem I am having now is that the query is just adding the points in the points column, instead of Looking at the first serial number, finding the device, then getting the points; going to the second serial number, finding the device, then getting the points for it, etc. and finally adding those two (or more) values together. Some serial numbers will reference the same device multiple times. I've tried everything I can think of. Thank you!

Comment: @willku - can you edit your question with an example of what it's doing, and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I've updated it and hopefully clarified a little bit. Thanks for your help!